# How put label on Bar button item?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna make calendar on navigation bar
Like on image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYPVY.png)

But i dont know how put label on image of calendar
Help me please
Thanks

Comment: Do want display current date on that image or simply any number with image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to add image and label on it in nav bar:

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "calenderImage"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonAction")), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 31) 
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 3, y: 5, width: 50, height: 20))// set position of label
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 16)// add font and size of label
        label.text = "your date number"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.backgroundColor =   UIColor.clear
        button.addSubview(label)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: It is working! Thank you